# How to parse html tag properties using bash and sed

Tags: bash, parsing, sed

I have several files containing lines with unique substring `NAME-`:

```
      <input type="hidden" name="NAME-00B5JZ" value="350.378,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-0599" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-7012" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-0096" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-0433" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-1100" value="0,00">
```

`name` and `value` html tag props are always different.

I need to get tab-separated values into separate files with names corresponding to original ones.

```
00B5JZ 350378,00
0599 0,00
0096 0,00
0433 0,00
1100 0,00
```

Dots should be removed from the `value`'s value

**EDIT**: I've decided to edit this post and give another aproach for whoever reads this:

let's say files are `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` with nothing else in the current directory:

```
for f in file*txt; do cat ${f} | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/<input.*name="NAME-//;s/" value="/\t/;s/">//;s/\.//g' > ${f//\.txt/_out\.txt}; done
```

1. first we get all filenames
2. `cat` them one by one and pass contents to `sed`
3. remove all whitespaces in the beginning of the line
4. remove everything up to the `name`'s value
5. replace everything between `name`'s value and `value`'s value with tab character
6. remove everything after `value`'s value
7. save result to a new file adding `_out` suffix to original filename right before `txt` file extension

Comment: Classical usage of a regular expression tool like `grep`. What did you try so far? Where are your attempts? What problem do you face? Don't just try to make others do your homework! You won't learn anything that way.

Comment: i used `grep` to find lines i needed, i didn't know what to do next....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed -e 's/.*NAME-\([^"]*\)" value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1\t\2/' -e 's/\.//g' INPUT.HTML
```

- `.*` any character zero or more times
- `[^"]*` any character but `"` repeated 0 or more times
- `\(...\)` captures the enclosed part, here the above substring up to the double quote is remembered in `\1` and the value is remembered in `\2`
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` substitutes the pattern with the replacement; here, it extracts the part after NAME- and the value and replaces the whole line with just the two captured parts separated by a tab (`\t`)
- `s/\.//g` deletes all dots (the `/g` means "global", i.e. all of them)

Answer (score 2):

**Grep Solution**

**Input**

```
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-00B5JZ" value="350.378,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-0599" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-7012" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-0096" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-0433" value="0,00">
       <input type="hidden" name="NAME-1100" value="0,00">
```

**Command**

```
$>  grep -Po "NAME-(.*) value=(.*)" INPUT_FILE  | tr '"|>|NAME\-|value=' ' ' | sed 's/\.//g'
```

**Note:** There is no space between "." and "*" inside grep  statement

**Output**

```
 00B5JZ       350.378,00
 0599         0,00
 7012         0,00
 0096         0,00
 0433         0,00
 1100         0,00
```

Comment: OP needs the `.` in `350.378,00` removed